# when running: npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss my-project, it only creates a gitignore and a readme file

Tags: npm, next.js, yarnpkg, npx

I'm trying to build a blog app from youtube tutorial, but I run

`npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss my-project`

it only creates a gitignore file and a readme file. Whats going wrong?

I was expecting for all the boilerplate with node_modules

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I think I have the solution, though I haven't fully tested it.

```
$ npm create-next-app --tailwind -with-tailwindcss-app project-folder-name
```

I referenced this repository on github for `with-tailwindcss`:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's been updated, if you run the command you listed, the README.md file that's downloaded contains the updated version of the command, in the case of npx that's:

```
npx create-next-app --tailwind with-tailwindcss-app
```

Adjusted to match your example, that's:

```
npx create-next-app --tailwind my-project
```